# Why am I getting the word "optional" before my placemarks on the app labels?

Tags: swift

EDIT: Full code now posted since it was requested.

Why am I getting the word "optional" before my placemarks on the app labels?

I originally unwrapped each property like this `\(p.thoroughfare!)`, and it worked, but only when there **was** a subThoroughfare. I couldn't unwrap `\(subThoroughfare)` because I don't know where to do it, therefore the app crashed when there **wasn't** a subThoroughfare.

[image]

```
    import UIKit
    import CoreLocation

    class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

var manager:CLLocationManager!


@IBOutlet var latitudeLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var longitudeLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var courseLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var speedLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var altitudeLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var addressLabel: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    manager = CLLocationManager()
    manager.delegate = self
    manager.desiredAccuracy - kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    manager.startUpdatingLocation()


}

//NOTE: [AnyObject] changed to [CLLocation]

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    print(locations)

    //userLocation - there is no need for casting, because we are now using CLLocation object

    var userLocation:CLLocation = locations[0]

    self.latitudeLabel.text = "\(userLocation.coordinate.latitude)"

    self.longitudeLabel.text = "\(userLocation.coordinate.longitude)"

    self.courseLabel.text = "\(userLocation.course)"

    self.speedLabel.text = "\(userLocation.speed)"

    self.altitudeLabel.text = "\(userLocation.altitude)"

    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(userLocation, completionHandler: { (placemarks, error) -> Void in

        if (error != nil) {

            print(error)

        } else {

            if let p = placemarks?[0] {

                var subThoroughfare : String = ""

                if (p.subThoroughfare != nil) {

                    subThoroughfare = p.subThoroughfare!

                }

                self.addressLabel.text = "\(subThoroughfare) \(p.thoroughfare) \n \(p.subLocality) \n \(p.subAdministrativeArea) \n \(p.postalCode) \n \(p.country)"

            }


        }

    })
```

Answer (score 2):

You are getting the `Optional("string")` because you are not unwrapping these optional vars.

if `var str:String?` is `nil` and you set `myLabel.text = str`, your label text will be empty! If it has a value let's say `str = "yaw!"` and you set `myLabel.text = str`, the label will show `yaw!`

Now if your string is `nil` and you use string interpolation `myLabel.text = \(str)`, your label text will show `nil`. If you set `str = "yaw!"` and `myLabel.text = \(str)`, the label will show `Optional("yaw!")`

**To solve your problem you have to unwrap your vars in a safe way:**

Create a var to hold the full string and then add the non nil values to this string.

```
    var fullString:String = ""
    if let _ = p.subThoroughfare { fullString += "\(p.subThoroughfare!)" } // Check if the attribute is not nil before adding it to the string
```

Replicate the 2nd line to every attribute `p.thoroughfare`, `p.subLocality` etc.

And finally, set `self.addressLabel.text = fullString`

Answer (score 0):

You are getting Optional("something") because:

1. Your variable is defined as an optional (meaning it could be nil).
2. You are using Swift.print() to display the string.

If it is not nil and you are not using Swift.print() to display the string, you will not get the word "Optional" and the string value in quotes, in parentheses.

You should check placemarks.count before attempting to accessing a value in the array, even if you use an array index of zero (as in your example code).  This should be part of your error checking.

As for the rest, I am not sure what you are trying to do.  If you can be more specific I might be able to give some suggestions.